# Joining lists in list together in python

Tags: list, for-comprehension

Stupidly basic question, but I have the following list:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

How do I join the elements together so it reads:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Cheers!

Comment: At least specify what language you are working in, and when you do, I'm pretty sure this will be a duplicate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools
a = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
print list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why do you even bother answering this question?